# Populating UITableView from Firestore

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

This feels very basic but I can't get it to work. The content read from FIrestore is not displayed in the tableview. From what I can gather the tableview is rendered before the `scheduleArray` array is populated from FIrestore. If I make the `scheduleArray` literal everything works just fine.
The print statement in `loadData()` function prints the content of the db just fine. So the connection to Firestore is working as expected.

How do I get the db read and array population to occur before the rendering of the tableview?

```
class ListScheduleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var scheduleIDarray = [String]() // <-- If this is made an array literal, everything works
    var db: Firestore!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        db = Firestore.firestore()
        loadData()

    }
    func loadData() {
        db.collection("schedules").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                    self.scheduleIDarray.append(document.documentID)
                }
            }
            print(self.scheduleIDarray) // <-- This prints the content in db correctly
        }
    }
       @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //Tableview setup
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

                print("Tableview setup \(scheduleIDarray.count)")
        return scheduleIDarray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customScheduleCell", for: indexPath) as! customScheduleviewCell
        let schedule = scheduleIDarray[indexPath.row]

        cell.scheduleName.text = schedule
        print("Array is populated \(scheduleIDarray)")
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: if you get successfully data from Firestore then reload tableview inside loadData() function

Comment: Did you set the `dataSource` and `delegate` of `tableView`?

Comment: @ChanchalChauhan you mean ”tableView.dataSource = self” and ”tableView.delegate = self”? I tried that. Perhaps I put them in the wrong place. I’ll check it after my day job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create an outlet of tableView in your viewController as:
`@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` and write given lines in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}
```

Reload tableView when you successfully received data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code, it might help someone else. There are no checks, no safety, just a very basic but working code.

```
class ListScheduleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var scheduleIDarray = [String]()
    var db: Firestore!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        loadData()

    }
    func loadData() {
        db.collection("schedules").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                    self.scheduleIDarray.append(document.documentID)
                }
            }
            print(self.scheduleIDarray) 

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
       @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //Tableview setup
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

                print("Tableview setup \(scheduleIDarray.count)")
        return scheduleIDarray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customScheduleCell", for: indexPath) as! customScheduleviewCell
        let schedule = scheduleIDarray[indexPath.row]

        cell.scheduleName.text = schedule
        print("Array is populated \(scheduleIDarray)")

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 things missing in the code

1 - you need to set the `UITableView` `datasource` to be able to load the data into in your `tableView`

2 - after get the data that you need from `Firestone` you need to reload your data by using `tableView.reloadData()` it will call the `tableViewDataSource` methods responsasses to populate your `tableView`